# What does, ‘elle fait grv golri’ mean?

Tags: argot, verlan

Someone said this to me on twitter so I assume there is slang involved.

Answer (score 8):

Slang indeed: that's a mix of abbreviation : *grave* → *grv* and *[verlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan)* : ri- gol(er) → gol - ri

> Elle fait grave rigoler (elle fait beaucoup rigoler)